# Test Class Coverage for Trigger with oldMap

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, trigger-oldmap

I have an Apex Trigger and Handler class on the Business Process object. When a lookup field (Financial_Planner__c) is updated on the Business Process, the system should query all Tasks associated to that Business Process and reassign all tasks that were assigned to the old Financial Planner to the new Financial Planner. (Note - it should only reassign tasks that are assigned to the Financial Planner, not all tasks associated to the Business Process, as there may be tasks assigned to other roles).

My Trigger works as expected in the UI, but I am unable to achieve 100% code coverage in my test class **and my SystemAssertEquals fails**. Thoughts?

Trigger:

```java
trigger BusinessProcessTrigger on FSTR__Business_Process__c (before insert, after insert, before update, after update) {

     if( Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate ){

        BusinessProcessTriggerHelper.financialPlannerUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);

     }}
```

Handler Class:

```java
public with sharing class BusinessProcessTriggerHelper {

    public static void financialPlannerUpdate(Map<Id, FSTR__Business_Process__c> newRecords, Map<Id,FSTR__Business_Process__c> oldRecords){

            Set<Id> changedRecordIds = new Set<Id>();    
            Set<Id> oldPlannerIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(Id recordId: newRecords.keySet()) {
                FSTR__Business_Process__c newRecord = newRecords.get(recordId);
                FSTR__Business_Process__c oldRecord = oldRecords.get(recordId);
                if(oldRecord.Financial_Planner__c != newRecord.Financial_Planner__c && newRecord.Financial_Planner__c != null) {
                    changedRecordIds.add(recordId);
                    oldPlannerIds.add(oldRecord.Financial_Planner__c);
                }
            }
    
            List<Task> taskLst = [SELECT Id, Subject, OwnerId, BP__c FROM Task WHERE BP__c IN :changedRecordIds AND OwnerId IN :oldPlannerIds];
            for(Task record: taskLst) {
                record.OwnerId = newRecords.get(record.BP__c).Financial_Planner__c;
            }
            update taskLst;
}}
```

Test Class:

```java
@istest public class BusinessProcessTriggerTest {

    @istest static void myUnitTest(){
        
        String uid = 'samUser';
        
        User u = new User(Alias = uid, Email= uid + '@myorg.com', 
          EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
          LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = userInfo.getProfileId(), 
          TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York', UserName= uid + '@myorg.com'); 
        insert u;
        
        Account myAccA = new Account();
        myAccA.Name = 'myAccA';
        myAccA.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        myAccA.recordtypeid=Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Household').getRecordTypeId();
        insert myAccA;
        
        FSTR__Business_Process__c biz = new FSTR__Business_Process__c();
        biz.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.FSTR__Business_Process__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Merit Workflows').getRecordTypeId();
        biz.Workflow__c = 'Client Review - IM/FP';
        biz.FSTR__Subject__c = 'Test Workflow';
        biz.Financial_Planner__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
        biz.FSTR__Due_Date__c = system.today();
        biz.FSTR__Business_Account__c = myAccA.Id;
        insert biz;

        Task t = new Task();
        t.recordtypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Advisor Task').getRecordTypeId();
        t.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        t.Status = 'Open';
        t.Subject = 'Test Task';
        t.ActivityDate = system.today();
        t.WhatId = myAccA.id;
        t.BP__c = biz.Id;
        insert t;

        Test.startTest();
        biz.Financial_Planner__c = u.id;
        update biz;
        Test.stopTest();

        biz = [SELECT Id, Financial_Planner__c FROM FSTR__Business_Process__c WHERE Id = :biz.Id];
        
        t = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, BP__c FROM Task WHERE BP__c =: biz.id];

        system.assertEquals(biz.Financial_Planner__c, t.OwnerId, 'No Match');
    }}
```

Code Coverage:

[image: code coverage]

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: Is your assertion failing? That should be the net result if this code is not covered. If the assertion is not failing, something else is going on.

Comment: Yes, the assertion is failing.

Comment: Can you try with [this rewrite](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/0077ee2bcf45768a58925bd5c45c20e9)? You'll also need to change the trigger logic to: `BusinessProcessTriggerHelper.financialPlannerUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);`

Comment: That code is definitely more efficient, and it works in the UI. However, It's still only 92% code coverage and the assertion in the test class is still failing.

Comment: You should never hard-code ids anywhere, for any reason. That said, if your assertion is failing, please **[edit]** your post to make that more clear.

Comment: As Adrian said, perhaps you might want to try creating a dummy user rather than a hard-coded Id? Users created in a unit test will disappear when the unit test reaches completion, so this is the preferred method for testing.

Comment: Is there any other automation in your org that might be mutating that Task and causing it not to match the query in the trigger handler?

Comment: There is no other automation touching the Task object in our org. Also, the trigger and helper class are working as expected in the UI - when I update Financial Planner in the sandbox, the appropriate tasks are updated.

Comment: Is there a reason for having that trigger operate both before and after insert/update?


On the before insert context, "changedRecordIds.add(recordId);" will just add nulls to the set.
On the after insert context, there won't be Tasks where BP__c matches the inserted id yet.


I think the best applicable context would be before update (and that makes after update unnecessary).

Comment: Not sure I follow. The helper class is only being called After Update...

if( Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate ){

        BusinessProcessTriggerHelper.financialPlannerUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);

     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be related to sharing rules. Removing `with sharing` from the helper class would be an easy way to tell - though that probably should not be the end solution.

Comment: That did it - removing `with sharing` gave me 100% code coverage and the assertEquals passed. Thanks!